# How to serialize empty arrays when converting to XML with Json.Net

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization, json.net

I need to convert some Json to XML but when I do it removes all empty arrays/list/collections/etc...

How can I get it to include the arrays as empty items?

Example Json:

```
{ 
  "EmptyCollection": [], 
  "OtherPorperty\": "TestValue" 
}
```

C# Code:

```
var jsonString = "{ \"EmptyCollection\": [], \"OtherPorperty\":\"TestValue\" }";


var xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString, "root", true);
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.InnerXml);
```

Actual result is

```
<root>
  <OtherPorperty>TestValue</OtherPorperty>
</root>
```

Desired result is

```
<root>
  <EmptyCollection></EmptyCollection>
  <OtherPorperty>TestValue</OtherPorperty>
</root> 

or 

<root>
  <EmptyCollection />
  <OtherPorperty>TestValue</OtherPorperty>
</root>
```

Using the writeArrayAtribute doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a problem with the meaning. Personally I believe that the conversion done by the Json library is fine as it is and you can't get one of the two results proposed by you.
The Tag  in every scenario proposed doesn't mean ( from XML point of view ) that it is an empty array. But it means that the property (not an array ) EmptyCollection is empty. You will lose something.

I suggest you to test for the absence of the tag as "no information" a.k.a "no entry in the array"

Comment: An empty element and empty collection are not strictly the same but it is a closer conversion than current. Currently it is lossy. I need to be able to convert it back but it is not possible as it states the field is required and is missing.

Comment: If you need the field one common approach should be define a null element. In many algorithms, like in a red-black tree, the leaf isn't a node with two null pointers but a node with null value. 

So instead having something like:
<Collection/>
You can try to obtain:
<Collection><MyElem>null<MyElem/></Collection>
or
<Collection><EmptyMyElem/></Collection>
(just as example)

Probably you need to use as source a Json like:
{ Collection:[ { myelem: null } ] }

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a large object graph that I am serializing and I don't really want to check all the collections and add null items to them and remove them again later.

Comment: One chance is to add the null element as last one in every case. ( Like in a C-String ). So your "JSON array / XML tag" is everytime filled with something and is easy to detect or skip